# Exceptionhandling with IOmniParallelTask not working

Tags: delphi, omnithreadlibrary

Unhandled exceptions within `IOmniParallelTask` execution should (as I understand the docs) be caught by the OTL and be attached to `IOmniTaskControl` instance, which may be accessed by the `termination handler` from `IOmniTaskConfig`.

So after setting up the `IOmniParallelTask` instance with a `termination handler` like this:

```
fTask := Parallel.ParallelTask.NoWait.NumTasks(1);
fTask.OnStop(HandleOnTaskStop);

fTask.TaskConfig(Parallel.TaskConfig.OnTerminated(HandleOnTaskThreadTerminated));
fTask.Execute(TaskToExecute);
```

any unhandled exceptions within `TaskToExecute`:

```
procedure TFormMain.TaskToExecute;
begin
  Winapi.Windows.Sleep(2000);
  raise Exception.Create('async operation exeption');
end;
```

should be attached to the `IOmniTaskControl` instance you get within the `termination handler`:

```
procedure TFormMain.HandleOnTaskThreadTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
begin
  if not Assigned(task.FatalException) then
    Exit;

  memo.Lines.Add('an exception occured: ' + task.FatalException.Message);
end;
```

The **issue** at this point is, that the **exception is not assigned** to `IOmniTaskControl.FatalException` and I have no clue why.

Maybe some of you guys have some ideas on what I am doing wrong. The whole VCL sampleproject may be found here: https://github.com/stackoverflow-samples/OTLTaskException

Comment: Looks like a bug/"feature" in the OTL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an abstraction layer problem. `Parallel.ParallelTask` stores threaded code exception in a local field which is not synchronized with the `IOmniTaskControl.FatalException` property. (I do agree that this is not a good behaviour but I'm not yet sure what would be the best way to fix that.)

Currently the only way to access caught exception of an `IOmniParallelTask` object is to call its `WaitFor` method. `IOmniParallelTask` should really expose a `FatalException`/`DetachException` pair, just like `IOmniParallelJoin`. (Again, an oversight, which should be fixed in the future.)

The best way to solve the problem with the current OTL is to call `WaitFor` in the termination handler and catch the exception there.

```
procedure TFormMain.HandleOnTaskThreadTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
begin
  try
    fTask.WaitFor(0);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      memo.Lines.Add('an exception occured: ' + E.Message);
  end;
  CleanupTask;
end;
```

I have also removed the `HandleOnTaskStop` and moved the cleanup to the termination handler. Otherwise, `fTask` was already `nil` at the time `HandleOnTaskThreadTerminated` was called.

---

EDIT

`DetachException`, `FatalException`, and `IsExceptional` have been added to the `IOmniParallelTask` so now you can simply do what you wanted in the first place (except that you have to use the `fTask`, not `task`).

```
procedure TFormMain.HandleOnTaskThreadTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
begin
  if not assigned(fTask.FatalException) then
    Exit;

  memo.Lines.Add('an exception occured: ' + FTask.FatalException.Message);
  CleanupTask;
end;
```

---

EDIT2

As noted in comments, `OnTerminate` handler relates to one task. In this example this is not a problem as the code makes sure that only one background task is running (`NumTasks(1)`).

In a general case, however, the `OnStop` handler should be used for this purpose.

```
procedure TFormMain.btnExecuteTaskClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(fTask) then
    Exit;

  memo.Lines.Add('task has been started..');
  fTask := Parallel.ParallelTask.NoWait.NumTasks(1);
  fTask.OnStop(HandleOnStop);
  fTask.Execute(TaskToExecute);
end;

procedure TFormMain.HandleOnStop;
begin
  if not assigned(fTask.FatalException) then
    Exit;

  memo.Lines.Add('an exception occured: ' + FTask.DetachException.Message);
  TThread.Queue(nil, CleanupTask);
end;
```

As `HandleOnStop` is called in a background thread (because `NoWait` is used), `CleanupTask` must be scheduled back to the main thread, as in the original code.

Comment: just for the record: as I understood the given event workflow, `HandleOnTaskThreadTerminated` should already get executed by the thread that triggered the `IOmniParallelTask` (in this case the mainthread). so queueing `CleanupTask` should be needless, shouldnt it?

Comment: thank you for the fast fix. i think it should be also mentioned that the given approach using `IOmniParallelTask.FatalException` only works for this particular issue using only one thread (`.Numtasks(1)`). In all other cases the downside of this fix is, that you must also ensure `fTask` is still alive, as the `termination handler` is being called every time a thread terminates. In my case this is no problem, as I am internally using another abstraction on top of the OTL.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. In this case it would be better to use OnStop handler, not OnTerminate handler. I'm adding this to the answer.